# how to redirect https to http in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a tomcat server that is currently running on port 8082(http).  I have to make the site https without touching the server code or tomcat configuration.  I installed nginx and could able to redirect the https to http, but the browser still says site is not secured.  How can we make the client use https and then nginx redirects to http internally, but to client all the calls are https.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass "http://localhost:8082/app/";
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;
        ssl_certificate      nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  nginx-selfsigned.key;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://localhost:8082/app$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is a reverse proxy, and this is implemented in Nginx using `proxy_pass`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use proxy_pass as Richard mentioned, so that you won't redirect to a backend URL via port 8082(That's the reason that broswer is accessing the http protocal directly. 
You also need to place a firewall rule to protect external access to this port

Comment: worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass "http://localhost:8082/app/";
        }
    }
 
 server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;
  ssl_certificate      nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  nginx-selfsigned.key;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://localhost:8082/app$1 permanent;
    }
}

Comment: Modified the original query.  When I type in https//localhost:443, it redirects to http from nginx, but once the user is logged in , the browser url again going back to http

Answer (score 0):

For your current config, just use the 443, and use proxy_pass in this listener, as simple as

```
server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;
        ssl_certificate      nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  nginx-selfsigned.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass "http://localhost:8082/app/";
        }
 }
```

You might be confused by the port 80, which should be redirected to 443 to ensure all traffics are HTTPS, like

```
server {
        listen       80;
        rewrite ^(.*) https://localhost/$1 permanent;
}
```

Also note these are pseudo code that I copied from your config, you need to try out and change later